# Spring security 5 and OAuth2 - Success Handler not being invoked and after login it is going into infinite loop

Tags: spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I am trying to migrate spring security to latest version (spring security 5.2.2 and Cloud OAuth2). As @EnableOAuth2Client is in maintenance mode now, I am trying to use http.oauth2Login() with customization for success handler. Following is my security class -

```
@Configuration
public class OAuth2SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
         .anyRequest().authenticated()
         .and()
         .oauth2Login().successHandler(new SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler("<url to redirect>"));
    }
}
```

I have registered client with name as 'custom'. Following is the flow in the browser -

`http://localhost:9000/oauth2/authorization/custom` -> IDP's login page and successful login -> Get Authorization code on URL `http://localhost:9000/login/oauth2/code/custom` -> it again goes to  `http://localhost:9000/oauth2/authorization/custom` and infinite loop. Successhandler is not invoked. Also, I don't see access token generation in logs.

I have tried many things in last two days like tweaking security config etc but nothing works.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with user info endpoint. My IDP has not exposed user info endpoint while it is mandatory in spring oauth2 where the request was failing. I needed to override the default OAuth2UserService implementation to resolve the issue.